# Are there 3rd party Facebook Application Development tests available online?

Tags: facebook

I am interested in hiring a virtual developer to write a Facebook application. But I would like to be able to have them complete a Facebook development test first (that I will pay them to take).

Not really interested in the multiple choice "pass/fail" test, but a test that requires actual code to be written.

Was wondering if there was a place where I could find a "test" that I could give potential Facebook Developers, and then I will have a developer friend evaluate their code.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how a non-developer could test the Facebook Developer skills of a virtual developer before hiring that developer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 having so much respect for their time that you're paying them to take your test!

Answer (score 3):

I've been developing Facebook apps for over 3 years and I know of no "tests" available. Facebook changes their API and platform so frequently, any tests would quickly become worthless and/or meaningless. The development platform is a bit of a mess right now with the switch the Graph API, Javascript API, iframe only apps and the requirement for using a secure connection.

I would suggest just starting with Facebook's own preferred developer's program. But just because a developer is not on the list, doesn't mean they are not a very knowledgeable and skilled Facebook platform developer.

Just for the record, I am not advertising or offering any services.
https://developers.facebook.com/preferreddevelopers/

Comment: Brent... Thanks for the info. I really can't afford an elite Facebook team (although I wish I could). My budget necessitates going off shore. Very reluctant to hire a developer without checking to see how they code. I know that doesn't eliminate all the risk, but would make me feel better. I have had problems in the past--have dealt with both very weak and very strong developers and I am not good in distinguishing between the two.

Comment: Facebook is a tough platform to determine if someone is good or not. They can be a very strong developer, but know nothing about the platform. The best you can do is look at apps they currently have live and ask them to send screen shots of the insights page for the app.

Comment: @BrentBaisley: insights doesn't reflect a good app or a good code, a good branding does :-)

Comment: @JOhn: I guess you need to search development communities and freelancing websites for good FB devs

Comment: Brent... Thanks for the input. No doubt you are right. Since you have been so helpful, I was wondering if you--or anyone else--could suggest a little assignment I might give the best 3 or 4 FB developers who have bid on my job. The bottom line for me is that the person funding the development of this project insists on evaluating completed assignments. He is willing to pay the developers. But I need to come up with a general assignment that will give us a sense of a developers general coding style and skill, plus give us a sense of how well they know FB. So maybe "test" is the wrong word.

Comment: Ask someone to create a basic page the does the "standard" social actions. Ask for basic permissions, ask for extended permissions, show users friends, post to wall, post to friend's wall, send a "request" to multiple friends (using Requests 2.0). An example app-vertisemet I did a few weeks ago that does all this, just for reference. http://apps.facebook.com/hpscrapbook